# Ring of Continuous functions of product space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces.

Is it true that $C(X \times Y, \mathbb{R}) \cong C(X,\mathbb{R}) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} C(Y,\mathbb{R})$ as real algebras?

Specifically, when is the canonical map $\Phi \colon C(X,\mathbb{R}) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} C(Y,\mathbb{R}) \to C(X \times Y, \mathbb{R})$ defined by $\Phi(f \otimes g) =f\cdot g$ bijective?

(For a topological space Z, $C(Z,\mathbb{R} )$ is the ring of continuous functions $Z \to \mathbb{R}$.)

This is of course true for finite discrete spaces, but I am not sure if this is true in general....

Comment: Well, if there is an isomorphism of algebras between the two, there might not be a natural one. In general I don't see a natural way to relate each $f(x,y)$ to some sort of finite linear combination of $[g_i(x),h_j(y)]$

Comment: But there is a canonical map $C(X,\mathbb{R}) \otimes_\mathbb{R} C(Y,\mathbb{R} \to C(X \times Y,\mathbb{R})$ defined by sending $(f \otimes g)$ to $f \cdot g$. The question is when is this map bijective?

Comment: Precisely my point: there is no obvious map in the other direction

Comment: @SergetheToaster You should add your comment to your question.

Comment: @ChrisSanders But does $C(X \times Y, \mathbb{R})$ satisfies the universal property of the tensor product?

Comment: You will probably need some sort of _topological_ tensor product. The Stone–Weierstrass theorem can be used to show that every continuous function on the product is a limit of finite sums of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C(X) \hat{\otimes}_\epsilon C(Y) = C(X\times Y)$, where $\hat{\otimes}_\epsilon$ is the injective tensor product. See "Ryan: *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces*, chapter 3" for more details.