# Spectrum of an injective tensor product

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, then from [Ring of Continuous functions of product space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392116/ring-of-continuous-functions-of-product-space) we know that $C(X \times Y) \cong C(X) \hat{\otimes}_\epsilon C(Y)$, where $\hat{\otimes}_\epsilon$ is the injective tensor product of the two $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

So my question is: What does $\text{Spec}(C(X) \hat{\otimes}_\epsilon C(Y))$ equal to? (where $\text{Spec}$ is the spectrum as rings).

Since for the "regular" tensor product, we know that the the spectrum of a tensor product is the fiber product of the spectra. But the injective tensor product is a bit different than the "regular" tensor product.

Comment: The relationship between $C(X) \hat{\otimes}_\epsilon C(Y)$ and $C(X \times Y)$ is somewhat analogous to that between $L^1$ and $L^\infty$ spaces. The injective tensor product captures a kind of "minimal" interaction between $X$ and $Y$, without making any assumptions on joint continuity of functions in $X \times Y$. Therefore, it is too coarse a space to carry a good analogue of the fiber product structure. I think, it appears that there is no explicit equivalent of the fibre product outcome in relation to the injective tensor product.